# How to solve gtk-warning on using gedit?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-netbook

I'm new in using ubuntu. I got the following error for several lines after changed 'grub' in /etc/default

(gedit:2996): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.NXBRZV': No such file or directory

During installation, I created 2 disk partition for ubuntu. One is swapspace. Another is for '/'.

Is this a big issue? How to solve? Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Right. You're running gedit as root, and root has its home in /root. But since root isn't a normal user, it doesn't have the normal directories like /home/user/.local/share/. In your case, it means that it can't store the list of recently edited files for gedit.

It is of absolutely no importance. But if you want that warning to go away, you can type "sudo mkdir /root/.local/share/". That will also let you open files that root has recently edited in gedit. But everything is fine :)